# Writing a dict with keys and dataframes to an excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the below dictionary which contains key as months and a dataframe.

[image]

The data and keys:

```
Data Period         Jan'18              Data Period     Jan'18              Data Period     Jan'18      
Churn Period        Feb'18              Churn Period    Mar'18              Churn Period    Apr'18      

Variable_Name       correlation         Variable_Name   correlation         Variable_Name   correlation
Pending_Disconnect  0.553395448         Pending_Change  0.043461995         active_frq_N    0.025697016
status_Active       0.539464806         status_Active   0.038057697         active_frq_Y    0.025697016
days_active         0.414774231         ethnic          0.037503202         ethnic          0.025195149
days_pend_disco     0.392915837         days_active     0.037227245         ecgroup         0.023192408
prop_tenure         0.074321692         archetype_grp   0.035761434         age             0.023121305
abs_change_3m       0.062267386         age_nan         0.035761434         archetype_nan   0.023121305
```

The keys and the dataframe have to be written to an excel sheet with a gap/s between each dataframe and key combination.

[image]

So the Data Period comes from the first part of key and churn period from the second part , after - .
Each dataframe contains data which looks like below:

```
Variable_Name       correlation 
Pending_Disconnect  0.553395448 
status_Active       0.539464806 
days_active         0.414774231 
days_pend_disco     0.392915837 
prop_tenure         0.074321692 
abs_change_3m       0.062267386
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1.) You should concat all dataframes of the dictionary and create a big dataframe.

Create an empty dataframe:

```
tmp = pd.Dataframe()
```

Iterate through the keys of your dictionary(let's say `d`) and concat the dfs:

```
for i in d.keys():
    tmp = pd.concat([tmp,d[key]], axis=1)
```

Now, `tmp` is a big df with all smaller dataframes concatenated.

2.) Append `blank columns` in this new df `tmp`. **The point here is that, every small df should be separated by a blank column with another small df.**

So, if there are 3 small df's, append 2 blank columns to `tmp`.

```
tmp[''] = ''
tmp[''] = ''
```

3.) Now, re-structure your `tmp` df by placing blank cols in between small dfs.

Suppose, columns in `tmp` are:

`'variable_name','correlation','Attribute','Datatype', 'variable_name','correlation','Attribute','Datatype',
'variable_name','correlation','Attribute','Datatype',
'',''  ## Last 2 cols are empty having blank values(step#2)`

These are columns for all small dfs which were concatenated.

Now, create a col_list and place a blank column between each small df:

```
col_list = ['variable_name','correlation','Attribute','Datatype', '', 'variable_name','correlation','Attribute','Datatype', '', 'variable_name','correlation','Attribute','Datatype']
```

4.) Re-arrange `tmp` as per `col_list`.

```
tmp = tmp[col_list]
```

5.) Now, you have this big dataframe ready with each small dataframe separated by a blank column with another.
Wrtie this into excel now.

```
tmp.to_excel() ## Fill all required parameters and write to excel.
```

Let me know if this helps.